# Visiting Australia both for tourism and visiting family, letter of invitation required for visa application?

Tags: indian-citizens, paperwork, australia, tourist-visas, applications

We are visiting Australia primarily for tourism, but we also have cousins who live there and plan to meet them. For our application, do we only need to show our hotel reservations, or do we also need to show a letter of invitation from our family? We are self-funding our trip.

More Context - We are Indian citizens applying online for the tourist visa. We'll be in Australia for around 20 days.

Answer (score 2):

If you have tourist visas, immigration will ask where you intend on staying, and your return tickets. You will have to provide an address on the immigration form they give you on the plane. There should not be any problem visiting relatives, so many people do that.

Comment: yes, and that can be any of the addresses you will stay if you're staying at multiple locations (like a tour across several cities, you only need to provide one of the hotels).